# Scaling TikZ from Gnuplot export

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, gnuplot, gnuplottex

Say we plotted in Gnuplot using terminal *tikz* resulting in output **tikz.tex** .
In our **main.tex** we

```
\include{tikz}
```

Now that messes up everything because the picture is way too large for our beamer document.

How can one scale down the tikzpicure without manually setting (e.g.) *scale=.5* in **tikz.tex**? The reason I want to avoid manual scaling is that I have many **tikz.tex**s and that they are not final yet.

Comment: Could you show an example `gnuplot` code? From the `gnuplot` docs it looks like you have the option to define the size of the generated plot, e.g. `set size 8cm,4cm`

Comment: The `size` or the `scale` option of the terminal solves my problem. If you put that as an answer, I accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gnuplot` has some options for setting the size of the generated graphic, cf. the manual (http://www.gnuplot.info/documentation.html):

- `set size x{unit},y{unit}` to set the exact size in your unit of choice, for example `set size 6cm,4cm`. The default is 12.5cm x 8.75cm. (Valid units are `cm`, `mm`, `in` or `inch`, `pt`, `pc`, `bp`, `dd`, `cc`.)
- `set scale x,y` to scale the figure relative to the size.

For reference, the default papersize in `beamer` is 128mm x 96mm, see section 8.3 in `beamer`s manual.

And by the way, one would typically use `\input` not `\include` to add snippets of code, see [When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include).

Comment: Notice the `scale` option is not available in all terminals, e.g. in _wxt_. See the terminals help via `set term terminalname help`.